# Powershell: get column number from CSV file header

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to get the column number from an imported CSV based on a particular column name (`$_."Status"`). Once I have the correct column number, I can assign it to a variable and use it in a foreach loop to write text to the corresponding cells. `$wsSource.cells.item($tr,49) = "Added by xyz)"` Note that the column position often varies from file to file.

I already have the index/row number via `$tr = $source.IndexOf($row)` ...but struggling with the col number.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Incomplete code from much larger PS script that writes two different excel files in the one loop:

```
$source = Import-Csv $csvFile
        $i = 2
        foreach($row in $source.where{$_.Contacted -like "*Invalid"})
        {
        $tr = ($source.IndexOf($row)+2)
        $wsTemp.cells.item($i,4) = $timeStamp
        $wsTemp.cells.item($i,10) = $row."Last Name"
        $wsSource.cells.item($tr,49) = "Added by xyz)"
        $wsSource.cells.item($tr,49).Interior.ColorIndex =19
         $i++
        }               
     }
    elseif ...
```

Comment: `$source[0].psobject.properties.IndexOf('Status')` will give you the column number of the `Status` header. Column numbers start at 0.

Comment: sounds to me that you are filling an Excel file with input from a csv.. The index numbers in a csv could very well not match those in the Excel files. Are there common column headers to match them on?

Comment: @AdminOfThings - Thanks for your help, but that doesn't quite seem to work... 

```
$source = Import-Csv $csvFile
$tc = $source[0].psobject.properties.IndexOf('Status')
Write-Host $tc
```
..."Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSNoteProperty] does not contain a method named 'IndexOf'"

Comment: @Theo - That's a good point, but in this case, the CSV header will always match the excel header. Unfortunately, the column position/number can vary somewhat between different excel files/sheets because users may add a couple extra columns, which breaks my hard-coded column reference (at column 49) `$wsSource.cells.item($tr,49) = "Added by xyz)"`

Comment: @AdminOfThings I think your code will work with the addition of `.name` specification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Hashtable to map the Excel column names with their index:

```
# create a hash with Excel column header names and their indices
$colMax    = $wsSource.UsedRange.Columns.Count
$xlHeaders = @{}
for ($col = 1; $col -le $colMax; $col++) {
    $name = $wsSource.Cells.Item(1, $col).Value()  # assuming the first row has the headers
    $xlHeaders[$name] = $col
}
```

Now you can match the column from the Csv with the column index in Excel like

```
if (!$xlHeaders.ContainsKey('Status')) {
    Write-Warning "Excel sheet does not have a column named 'Status'"
}
else {
    $xlColumn = $xlHeaders['Status']
    $wsSource.Cells.Item($tr, $xlColumn) = "Added by xyz)"
    $wsSource.Cells.Item($tr, $xlColumn).Interior.ColorIndex = 19
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks very much for the detailed reply, Theo...
Jason